# (Kotlin)NullPointerException in textview using callback with Dagger 2 object instance

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

NullPointerException in textview when I try to change text by dagger 2 instance object. Note: Using a common instance (new Myobjcet(this)) works.

## Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MyCallBack{

        @Inject
        lateinit var myObject: MyObject

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            mytextview.text = "first change"

            val myComponent = (application as App).myComponent
            myComponent.inject(this)

        }

        override fun callBack(string: String) {
            try {
                mytextview.text = string
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("xxx", e.toString())
            }
        }
    }
```

## Object

```
    class MyObject(var res: MyCallBack) {
    init {
        res.callBack("second change")
    }
}
```

## Component

```
@Component(modules = MyModule.class)
public interface MyComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

## Module

```
@Module
class MyModule {

@Provides
fun proviesMyObject(): MyObject = MyObject(MainActivity())
}
```

Comment: Where and how is `mytextview` initialized?

Comment: Using kotlin dont need initialized, just need the id, in this case is **android:id="@+id/mytextview"**.

Comment: @user2340612 i think @Tuite means he's using Kotlin Android Extensions, whereby you can refer to `View`s in a declarative layout by their IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem stems from the fact that you're manually instantiating `MainActivity` when constructing `MyObject` in your module. because it is manually constructed, it isn't managed by the framework and is therefore not run through it's expected lifecycle (e.g. `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, `onResume()`, etc).

(side note - never do this in production code).

since `onCreate()` never runs for that manually constructed instance, the layout for that instance isn't inflated, so `MyObject` is referring to an `Activity` (as an implementation of `MyCallBack`) that has no awareness of any `View`s.

if you want to involve a valid, framework-managed instance of `MyActivity` in your object graph, one solution is to add it as a required constructor parameter to your module, like so:

```
@Module
class MyModule(private val myCallBack: MyCallBack) {
    @Provides 
    fun providesMyObject(): MyObject = MyObject(myCallBack)
}
```

...then, in `MainActivity` construct the component and perform self-injection, like so:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

    mytextview.text = "first change"

    DaggerMyComponent.builder()
            .myModule(MyModule(this))
            .build()
            .inject(this)
}
```

hope that helps clear things up!

Comment: works like a charm, thx bro. I think doing `inject(this)` I was adding a MainActivity instance in the **graph**.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your Module, you are instantiating a new MainActivity that is different from the one instantiated by the framework. You need to realize that if you manually instantiated an activity, its views will not be inflated, hence the NullPointerException. I suggest you pass the instance of your activity in your module instead.

```
@Module
class MyModule(val res: MyCallBack) {

    @Provides
    fun providesMyObject(): MyObject = MyObject(res)
}
```

Instantiate your component in MainActivity like

```
val myComponent = DaggerMyComponent.builder()
    .myModule(MyModule(this))
    .build()
myComponent.inject(this)
```